# c++ Class inheritance with functions

Tags: c++, inheritance, pointers, virtual-functions

I have been studying c++ for an exam and I thought that i had understood most of the c++ commons misconcemptions with much fatigue but i've encountered an exercise from a past exam that is driving me crazy, it combines virtual methods and inheritance in a way that i dont seem to understand here is the code:

```
    #include <iostream>

    class B;

class A {
    public:
    virtual A* set(A* a) = 0;
};

class B : public A {
    public:
    virtual A* set(B* b) {
            std::cout << "set1 has been called" << std::endl;
            b = this;
            return b;
    }

    virtual B* set(A* a) {
            std::cout << "set2 has been called" << std::endl;
            a = this;
            return this;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    B *b = new B();
    A *a = b->set(b);
    a = b->set(a);
    a = a->set(b);
    a = a->set(a);
    return 0;
}
```

the output is

```
set1 has been called
set2 has been called
set2 has been called
set2 has been called
```

From what i've gathered the first call (b->set(b) ) calls the first method of class B and return b itself and then this objectref gets casted to A  meaning that now the object b is now of type A?
 so i have A *a = A *b;
now it makes sense to me that i should call set of A since i have this situation in my mind
`objectoftypeA->set(objectoftypeA)` so i m not supposed to look into virtual methods since the two object are base classes ?

Anyway as you can see I have much confusion so bear with me if i make stupid errors i would be glad if someone could explain whats going on this code,i tried to search the web but i find only small and easy example that dont cause troubles.

Comment: It would be helpful if you described what you *expect*. You've just thrown a lot of code at us, and described in a run-on sentence what you're *not* sure of, which is a bit hard to follow. Hard to know where to start answering.

Comment: I would expect that the second call calls again set1 but it doesnt so i guess that my whole line of thinking is wrong

Comment: Im not quite sure on this but the example is really confusing though. IMO i think `virtual B* set(A* a)` alias `set2` will act as implementation of `virtual A* set(A* a) = 0;` as a `B*` can implicitely be casted to an `A*`. Thus once you received a `A*` from `set1` the implmentatino will be called which is `set2`. EDIT: Notice that `set1` cant implement the pure virtual function due to its specialied parameter. Try to comment out each function. I gueess ` B *b = new B();` will cause an error if `set2` is not there but not if `set1` is not there.

Comment: Please don't write code like this yourself :)

Comment: @jrok This could easily happen in real life, although one should always be careful when mixing overloading with overriding. C++11 provides pseudo-keywords `final` and `override` to prevent accidentally writing this sort of thing.

Comment: Btw im not dead im trying to make sense of all the things you have wrote,i think i understand why `virtual B* set(A* a)` is an alias of `virtual A* set(A* a)` is it because b has the relantionship of B-is-a-A?Also if i write `A *a = new B()` does this object has static type A and dynamic type B? Thanks everyone for the answers

Comment: @kdma: You need to explicitly state what confuses you. You can't expect me to explain that if you just give up with "my thought process must be wrong so it's not relevant." This is important, and unintuitive: the return type does not participate in overloading. So no matter the return type `R`, `R B::set(A*)` will override `A A::set(A*)`. Having different return types is disallowed unless the derived class returns a type derived from the return type of the base class. So yes, it's a particular kind of is-a relationship. This special case is called *covariance.*

Comment: Let me try to explain those 3 set looks the same to me since B is a derived of A after the first call i would have object b of type A so the second call would be the first set of A,but its not!i really dont get it, i am trying but it seems that i missing something that you all have in your mind :)

Comment: i mean since a has static type A if i call b(object of type A)->set(a(objectoftype A) why should i look into virtual methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Potatoswatter is right, but I think I have a bit "clearer" explanation.  I think the OP is getting confused on what happens at run-time with dynamic type lookup versus compile-time, and when up-casting happens automatically, versus when it does not.

First off, return type does NOT affect which overload is called.  You probably know that, but it bears repeating.  A return type mis-match will cause an error at compile-time, but not run-time, and does not affect which overload is called.  Also it's worth noting that as long as it is a compatible pointer type (in a hierarchy together) returning a pointer doesn't ever "change" it.  It is still the same pointer, unlike converting floats to ints, where there is an actual change.

Now to go through the calls one-by-one.  This is my understanding of the process, not necessarily what the standard, or what "really" happens.

When you call `b->set(b)` the compiler (not run-time) goes "looking for a method named *set* with an argument of *pointer to B*" which it finds with the one that outputs set1.  It's virtual, so there's code to check if the class points to anything lower, but there isn't, so it just calls it, and returns the `this` pointer into `a`.

Now you're calling `b->set(a)`.  Again it's the compiler that goes "does *b* have an overload that takes *pointer to A*?"  Yes it does, so it calls the "set2" method. It's the compiler that sees an `A*` and so the call is "determined" at that point.  Even though the pointer points to an object that is of type B, the compiler doesn't know that, or care.  So it's the compile-time types of the *arguments* that determine which overloaded method get taken.  From that point on, where in the hierarchy the virtual gets taken is on the underlying type of the `this` pointer, but only downward.

Here's a different case though.  Try this: `b->set(dynamic_cast<B*>(a))`  This should call the "set1" method, because the compiler is going to definitely have a pointer to B (even if it's `nullptr`).

Now the third case: `a->set(b)`.  What's happening here is the compiler says "there is only one `set` method, so can the argument be up-cast or constructed to that type?"  The answer is yes, as `B` is a child of `A`.  So that cast happens transparantly, and the compiler calls the ABSTRACT dispatcher for the set method of the type A. This occurs at compile time **before** the "real" type of what `a` is pointer to.  Then at run-time, the program "walks the virtual" and finds the lowest one, the `B->set(A*)` method that emits "set2".  The actual type of what the argument points to isn't used, only the type to the left of the arrow operator, and that only determines how far down the hierarchy.

And the fourth case is just the 3rd again.  The type of the argument (the pointer, not whta is pointed to) is compatible, so it goes as before.  If you want a dramatic demonstration of this, try this:

```
a->set((A*)nullptr) // prints "set2 has been called"
b->set((A*)nullptr) // prints "set2 has been called"
b->set((B*)nullptr) // prints "set1 has been called"
```

The underlying type of what the arguments point to doesn't affect dynamic dispatch.  Only their "surface" type affects the overload called.

Comment: I finally get it your explanation was simplier and more targeted to my unknowledge of c++ i wish my teacher could explain like this,some people forget that everyone start with no knowledge and need a walkthrough for some things

Answer (score 4):

The program demonstrates how member functions are looked up. The static type of the object determines the function overload that will be called: it performs the name lookup. The dynamic type then determines the virtual override that gets called.

Perhaps the key point is that different overlods of the same name are really different functions.

Since `A` has only one `set` member, there is only one thing that can happen when you call `a->set()`, no matter what the argument is. But when you call `b->set()`, there are a couple potential functions, and the best one is selected.

Since `B::set` is never overridden, it makes no difference whether it's `virtual` or not. `virtual` members of the same class don't talk to each other at all.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Yeah, it's like that… 90% of the work is outside the programming aspects.